# Positioning SKNode according to a CoreML prediction

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, augmented-reality, arkit, coreml

I'm taking a look at this [CoreML and ARKit example](https://dev.to/osterbergjordan/arkit--vision-an-intriguing-combination), but the source project is not showing the `SKLabelNode`s when I run it. My guess is that they are lacking a value `position`, and I'd like to place the labels where the predicted objects are located in the screen. This example is using the `Inceptionv3` ML model.

The labels are added in the view controller's `view(_ view: ARSKView, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SKNode?` method:

```
func view(_ view: ARSKView, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SKNode? {

    // Code here to get `identifier`

    let labelNode = SKLabelNode(text: identifier)
    labelNode.horizontalAlignmentMode = .center
    labelNode.verticalAlignmentMode = .center
    labelNode.fontName = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16).fontName
    return labelNode
}
```

I tried to set a position for `labelNode` doing

```
labelNode.position = (view.node(for: anchor)?.position)!
```

but I don't get any value there.

How could I do this?